# Rejecting class because it failed compile-time verification

Tags: java, android, elliptic-curve

I am trying to integrate curve25519-java from openwhispersystems into my Android app and compiling it with API 23 (Marshmallow). When using non native code I get this runtime exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class org.whispersystems.curve25519.java.fe_mul because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'org.whispersystems.curve25519.java.fe_mul' appears in /data/app/com.fenritz.safecam-1/base.apk)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.java.ge_madd.ge_madd(ge_madd.java:65)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.java.ge_scalarmult_base.ge_scalarmult_base(ge_scalarmult_base.java:96)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.java.curve_sigs.curve25519_keygen(curve_sigs.java:30)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.BaseJavaCurve25519Provider.generatePublicKey(BaseJavaCurve25519Provider.java:50)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.JavaCurve25519Provider.generatePublicKey(JavaCurve25519Provider.java:8)
      at org.whispersystems.curve25519.Curve25519.generateKeyPair(Curve25519.java:70)
      at com.fenritz.safecam.SafeCameraActivity.onCreate(SafeCameraActivity.java:105)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Class that is being rejected is following:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package org.whispersystems.curve25519.java;

public class fe_mul {
    public fe_mul() {
    }

    public static void fe_mul(int[] h, int[] f, int[] g) {
        int f0 = f[0];
        int f1 = f[1];
        int f2 = f[2];
        int f3 = f[3];
        int f4 = f[4];
        int f5 = f[5];
        int f6 = f[6];
        int f7 = f[7];
        int f8 = f[8];
        int f9 = f[9];
        int g0 = g[0];
        int g1 = g[1];
        int g2 = g[2];
        int g3 = g[3];
        int g4 = g[4];
        int g5 = g[5];
        int g6 = g[6];
        int g7 = g[7];
        int g8 = g[8];
        int g9 = g[9];
        int g1_19 = 19 * g1;
        int g2_19 = 19 * g2;
        int g3_19 = 19 * g3;
        int g4_19 = 19 * g4;
        int g5_19 = 19 * g5;
        int g6_19 = 19 * g6;
        int g7_19 = 19 * g7;
        int g8_19 = 19 * g8;
        int g9_19 = 19 * g9;
        int f1_2 = 2 * f1;
        int f3_2 = 2 * f3;
        int f5_2 = 2 * f5;
        int f7_2 = 2 * f7;
        int f9_2 = 2 * f9;
        long f0g0 = (long)f0 * (long)g0;
        long f0g1 = (long)f0 * (long)g1;
        long f0g2 = (long)f0 * (long)g2;
        long f0g3 = (long)f0 * (long)g3;
        long f0g4 = (long)f0 * (long)g4;
        long f0g5 = (long)f0 * (long)g5;
        long f0g6 = (long)f0 * (long)g6;
        long f0g7 = (long)f0 * (long)g7;
        long f0g8 = (long)f0 * (long)g8;
        long f0g9 = (long)f0 * (long)g9;
        long f1g0 = (long)f1 * (long)g0;
        long f1g1_2 = (long)f1_2 * (long)g1;
        long f1g2 = (long)f1 * (long)g2;
        long f1g3_2 = (long)f1_2 * (long)g3;
        long f1g4 = (long)f1 * (long)g4;
        long f1g5_2 = (long)f1_2 * (long)g5;
        long f1g6 = (long)f1 * (long)g6;
        long f1g7_2 = (long)f1_2 * (long)g7;
        long f1g8 = (long)f1 * (long)g8;
        long f1g9_38 = (long)f1_2 * (long)g9_19;
        long f2g0 = (long)f2 * (long)g0;
        long f2g1 = (long)f2 * (long)g1;
        long f2g2 = (long)f2 * (long)g2;
        long f2g3 = (long)f2 * (long)g3;
        long f2g4 = (long)f2 * (long)g4;
        long f2g5 = (long)f2 * (long)g5;
        long f2g6 = (long)f2 * (long)g6;
        long f2g7 = (long)f2 * (long)g7;
        long f2g8_19 = (long)f2 * (long)g8_19;
        long f2g9_19 = (long)f2 * (long)g9_19;
        long f3g0 = (long)f3 * (long)g0;
        long f3g1_2 = (long)f3_2 * (long)g1;
        long f3g2 = (long)f3 * (long)g2;
        long f3g3_2 = (long)f3_2 * (long)g3;
        long f3g4 = (long)f3 * (long)g4;
        long f3g5_2 = (long)f3_2 * (long)g5;
        long f3g6 = (long)f3 * (long)g6;
        long f3g7_38 = (long)f3_2 * (long)g7_19;
        long f3g8_19 = (long)f3 * (long)g8_19;
        long f3g9_38 = (long)f3_2 * (long)g9_19;
        long f4g0 = (long)f4 * (long)g0;
        long f4g1 = (long)f4 * (long)g1;
        long f4g2 = (long)f4 * (long)g2;
        long f4g3 = (long)f4 * (long)g3;
        long f4g4 = (long)f4 * (long)g4;
        long f4g5 = (long)f4 * (long)g5;
        long f4g6_19 = (long)f4 * (long)g6_19;
        long f4g7_19 = (long)f4 * (long)g7_19;
        long f4g8_19 = (long)f4 * (long)g8_19;
        long f4g9_19 = (long)f4 * (long)g9_19;
        long f5g0 = (long)f5 * (long)g0;
        long f5g1_2 = (long)f5_2 * (long)g1;
        long f5g2 = (long)f5 * (long)g2;
        long f5g3_2 = (long)f5_2 * (long)g3;
        long f5g4 = (long)f5 * (long)g4;
        long f5g5_38 = (long)f5_2 * (long)g5_19;
        long f5g6_19 = (long)f5 * (long)g6_19;
        long f5g7_38 = (long)f5_2 * (long)g7_19;
        long f5g8_19 = (long)f5 * (long)g8_19;
        long f5g9_38 = (long)f5_2 * (long)g9_19;
        long f6g0 = (long)f6 * (long)g0;
        long f6g1 = (long)f6 * (long)g1;
        long f6g2 = (long)f6 * (long)g2;
        long f6g3 = (long)f6 * (long)g3;
        long f6g4_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g4_19;
        long f6g5_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g5_19;
        long f6g6_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g6_19;
        long f6g7_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g7_19;
        long f6g8_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g8_19;
        long f6g9_19 = (long)f6 * (long)g9_19;
        long f7g0 = (long)f7 * (long)g0;
        long f7g1_2 = (long)f7_2 * (long)g1;
        long f7g2 = (long)f7 * (long)g2;
        long f7g3_38 = (long)f7_2 * (long)g3_19;
        long f7g4_19 = (long)f7 * (long)g4_19;
        long f7g5_38 = (long)f7_2 * (long)g5_19;
        long f7g6_19 = (long)f7 * (long)g6_19;
        long f7g7_38 = (long)f7_2 * (long)g7_19;
        long f7g8_19 = (long)f7 * (long)g8_19;
        long f7g9_38 = (long)f7_2 * (long)g9_19;
        long f8g0 = (long)f8 * (long)g0;
        long f8g1 = (long)f8 * (long)g1;
        long f8g2_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g2_19;
        long f8g3_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g3_19;
        long f8g4_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g4_19;
        long f8g5_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g5_19;
        long f8g6_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g6_19;
        long f8g7_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g7_19;
        long f8g8_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g8_19;
        long f8g9_19 = (long)f8 * (long)g9_19;
        long f9g0 = (long)f9 * (long)g0;
        long f9g1_38 = (long)f9_2 * (long)g1_19;
        long f9g2_19 = (long)f9 * (long)g2_19;
        long f9g3_38 = (long)f9_2 * (long)g3_19;
        long f9g4_19 = (long)f9 * (long)g4_19;
        long f9g5_38 = (long)f9_2 * (long)g5_19;
        long f9g6_19 = (long)f9 * (long)g6_19;
        long f9g7_38 = (long)f9_2 * (long)g7_19;
        long f9g8_19 = (long)f9 * (long)g8_19;
        long f9g9_38 = (long)f9_2 * (long)g9_19;
        long h0 = f0g0 + f1g9_38 + f2g8_19 + f3g7_38 + f4g6_19 + f5g5_38 + f6g4_19 + f7g3_38 + f8g2_19 + f9g1_38;
        long h1 = f0g1 + f1g0 + f2g9_19 + f3g8_19 + f4g7_19 + f5g6_19 + f6g5_19 + f7g4_19 + f8g3_19 + f9g2_19;
        long h2 = f0g2 + f1g1_2 + f2g0 + f3g9_38 + f4g8_19 + f5g7_38 + f6g6_19 + f7g5_38 + f8g4_19 + f9g3_38;
        long h3 = f0g3 + f1g2 + f2g1 + f3g0 + f4g9_19 + f5g8_19 + f6g7_19 + f7g6_19 + f8g5_19 + f9g4_19;
        long h4 = f0g4 + f1g3_2 + f2g2 + f3g1_2 + f4g0 + f5g9_38 + f6g8_19 + f7g7_38 + f8g6_19 + f9g5_38;
        long h5 = f0g5 + f1g4 + f2g3 + f3g2 + f4g1 + f5g0 + f6g9_19 + f7g8_19 + f8g7_19 + f9g6_19;
        long h6 = f0g6 + f1g5_2 + f2g4 + f3g3_2 + f4g2 + f5g1_2 + f6g0 + f7g9_38 + f8g8_19 + f9g7_38;
        long h7 = f0g7 + f1g6 + f2g5 + f3g4 + f4g3 + f5g2 + f6g1 + f7g0 + f8g9_19 + f9g8_19;
        long h8 = f0g8 + f1g7_2 + f2g6 + f3g5_2 + f4g4 + f5g3_2 + f6g2 + f7g1_2 + f8g0 + f9g9_38;
        long h9 = f0g9 + f1g8 + f2g7 + f3g6 + f4g5 + f5g4 + f6g3 + f7g2 + f8g1 + f9g0;
        long carry0 = h0 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h1 += carry0;
        h0 -= carry0 << 26;
        long carry4 = h4 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h5 += carry4;
        h4 -= carry4 << 26;
        long carry1 = h1 + 16777216L >> 25;
        h2 += carry1;
        h1 -= carry1 << 25;
        long carry5 = h5 + 16777216L >> 25;
        h6 += carry5;
        h5 -= carry5 << 25;
        long carry2 = h2 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h3 += carry2;
        h2 -= carry2 << 26;
        long carry6 = h6 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h7 += carry6;
        h6 -= carry6 << 26;
        long carry3 = h3 + 16777216L >> 25;
        h4 += carry3;
        h3 -= carry3 << 25;
        long carry7 = h7 + 16777216L >> 25;
        h8 += carry7;
        h7 -= carry7 << 25;
        carry4 = h4 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h5 += carry4;
        h4 -= carry4 << 26;
        long carry8 = h8 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h9 += carry8;
        h8 -= carry8 << 26;
        long carry9 = h9 + 16777216L >> 25;
        h0 += carry9 * 19L;
        h9 -= carry9 << 25;
        carry0 = h0 + 33554432L >> 26;
        h1 += carry0;
        h0 -= carry0 << 26;
        h[0] = (int)h0;
        h[1] = (int)h1;
        h[2] = (int)h2;
        h[3] = (int)h3;
        h[4] = (int)h4;
        h[5] = (int)h5;
        h[6] = (int)h6;
        h[7] = (int)h7;
        h[8] = (int)h8;
        h[9] = (int)h9;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how why it's being rejected and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown because of too many variable in single method. Just dividing it to two method fixes the issue. Here is the fix:

```
package org.whispersystems.curve25519.java;

public class fe_mul {

//CONVERT #include "fe.h"
//CONVERT #include "long.h"

/*
h = f * g
Can overlap h with f or g.

Preconditions:
   |f| bounded by 1.65*2^26,1.65*2^25,1.65*2^26,1.65*2^25,etc.
   |g| bounded by 1.65*2^26,1.65*2^25,1.65*2^26,1.65*2^25,etc.

Postconditions:
   |h| bounded by 1.01*2^25,1.01*2^24,1.01*2^25,1.01*2^24,etc.
*/

/*
Notes on implementation strategy:

Using schoolbook multiplication.
Karatsuba would save a little in some cost models.

Most multiplications by 2 and 19 are 32-bit precomputations;
cheaper than 64-bit postcomputations.

There is one remaining multiplication by 19 in the carry chain;
one *19 precomputation can be merged into this,
but the resulting data flow is considerably less clean.

There are 12 carries below.
10 of them are 2-way parallelizable and vectorizable.
Can get away with 11 carries, but then data flow is much deeper.

With tighter constraints on inputs can squeeze carries into int32.
*/

private static long[] fe_mul1(int[] f,int[] g){
  int f0 = f[0];
  int f1 = f[1];
  int f2 = f[2];
  int f3 = f[3];
  int f4 = f[4];
  int f5 = f[5];
  int f6 = f[6];
  int f7 = f[7];
  int f8 = f[8];
  int f9 = f[9];
  int g0 = g[0];
  int g1 = g[1];
  int g2 = g[2];
  int g3 = g[3];
  int g4 = g[4];
  int g5 = g[5];
  int g6 = g[6];
  int g7 = g[7];
  int g8 = g[8];
  int g9 = g[9];
  int g1_19 = 19 * g1; /* 1.959375*2^29 */
  int g2_19 = 19 * g2; /* 1.959375*2^30; still ok */
  int g3_19 = 19 * g3;
  int g4_19 = 19 * g4;
  int g5_19 = 19 * g5;
  int g6_19 = 19 * g6;
  int g7_19 = 19 * g7;
  int g8_19 = 19 * g8;
  int g9_19 = 19 * g9;
  int f1_2 = 2 * f1;
  int f3_2 = 2 * f3;
  int f5_2 = 2 * f5;
  int f7_2 = 2 * f7;
  int f9_2 = 2 * f9;
  long f0g0    = f0   * (long) g0;
  long f0g1    = f0   * (long) g1;
  long f0g2    = f0   * (long) g2;
  long f0g3    = f0   * (long) g3;
  long f0g4    = f0   * (long) g4;
  long f0g5    = f0   * (long) g5;
  long f0g6    = f0   * (long) g6;
  long f0g7    = f0   * (long) g7;
  long f0g8    = f0   * (long) g8;
  long f0g9    = f0   * (long) g9;
  long f1g0    = f1   * (long) g0;
  long f1g1_2  = f1_2 * (long) g1;
  long f1g2    = f1   * (long) g2;
  long f1g3_2  = f1_2 * (long) g3;
  long f1g4    = f1   * (long) g4;
  long f1g5_2  = f1_2 * (long) g5;
  long f1g6    = f1   * (long) g6;
  long f1g7_2  = f1_2 * (long) g7;
  long f1g8    = f1   * (long) g8;
  long f1g9_38 = f1_2 * (long) g9_19;
  long f2g0    = f2   * (long) g0;
  long f2g1    = f2   * (long) g1;
  long f2g2    = f2   * (long) g2;
  long f2g3    = f2   * (long) g3;
  long f2g4    = f2   * (long) g4;
  long f2g5    = f2   * (long) g5;
  long f2g6    = f2   * (long) g6;
  long f2g7    = f2   * (long) g7;
  long f2g8_19 = f2   * (long) g8_19;
  long f2g9_19 = f2   * (long) g9_19;
  long f3g0    = f3   * (long) g0;
  long f3g1_2  = f3_2 * (long) g1;
  long f3g2    = f3   * (long) g2;
  long f3g3_2  = f3_2 * (long) g3;
  long f3g4    = f3   * (long) g4;
  long f3g5_2  = f3_2 * (long) g5;
  long f3g6    = f3   * (long) g6;
  long f3g7_38 = f3_2 * (long) g7_19;
  long f3g8_19 = f3   * (long) g8_19;
  long f3g9_38 = f3_2 * (long) g9_19;
  long f4g0    = f4   * (long) g0;
  long f4g1    = f4   * (long) g1;
  long f4g2    = f4   * (long) g2;
  long f4g3    = f4   * (long) g3;
  long f4g4    = f4   * (long) g4;
  long f4g5    = f4   * (long) g5;
  long f4g6_19 = f4   * (long) g6_19;
  long f4g7_19 = f4   * (long) g7_19;
  long f4g8_19 = f4   * (long) g8_19;
  long f4g9_19 = f4   * (long) g9_19;
  long f5g0    = f5   * (long) g0;
  long f5g1_2  = f5_2 * (long) g1;
  long f5g2    = f5   * (long) g2;
  long f5g3_2  = f5_2 * (long) g3;
  long f5g4    = f5   * (long) g4;
  long f5g5_38 = f5_2 * (long) g5_19;
  long f5g6_19 = f5   * (long) g6_19;
  long f5g7_38 = f5_2 * (long) g7_19;
  long f5g8_19 = f5   * (long) g8_19;
  long f5g9_38 = f5_2 * (long) g9_19;
  long f6g0    = f6   * (long) g0;
  long f6g1    = f6   * (long) g1;
  long f6g2    = f6   * (long) g2;
  long f6g3    = f6   * (long) g3;
  long f6g4_19 = f6   * (long) g4_19;
  long f6g5_19 = f6   * (long) g5_19;
  long f6g6_19 = f6   * (long) g6_19;
  long f6g7_19 = f6   * (long) g7_19;
  long f6g8_19 = f6   * (long) g8_19;
  long f6g9_19 = f6   * (long) g9_19;
  long f7g0    = f7   * (long) g0;
  long f7g1_2  = f7_2 * (long) g1;
  long f7g2    = f7   * (long) g2;
  long f7g3_38 = f7_2 * (long) g3_19;
  long f7g4_19 = f7   * (long) g4_19;
  long f7g5_38 = f7_2 * (long) g5_19;
  long f7g6_19 = f7   * (long) g6_19;
  long f7g7_38 = f7_2 * (long) g7_19;
  long f7g8_19 = f7   * (long) g8_19;
  long f7g9_38 = f7_2 * (long) g9_19;
  long f8g0    = f8   * (long) g0;
  long f8g1    = f8   * (long) g1;
  long f8g2_19 = f8   * (long) g2_19;
  long f8g3_19 = f8   * (long) g3_19;
  long f8g4_19 = f8   * (long) g4_19;
  long f8g5_19 = f8   * (long) g5_19;
  long f8g6_19 = f8   * (long) g6_19;
  long f8g7_19 = f8   * (long) g7_19;
  long f8g8_19 = f8   * (long) g8_19;
  long f8g9_19 = f8   * (long) g9_19;
  long f9g0    = f9   * (long) g0;
  long f9g1_38 = f9_2 * (long) g1_19;
  long f9g2_19 = f9   * (long) g2_19;
  long f9g3_38 = f9_2 * (long) g3_19;
  long f9g4_19 = f9   * (long) g4_19;
  long f9g5_38 = f9_2 * (long) g5_19;
  long f9g6_19 = f9   * (long) g6_19;
  long f9g7_38 = f9_2 * (long) g7_19;
  long f9g8_19 = f9   * (long) g8_19;
  long f9g9_38 = f9_2 * (long) g9_19;
  long h[] = new long[10];
  h[0] = f0g0+f1g9_38+f2g8_19+f3g7_38+f4g6_19+f5g5_38+f6g4_19+f7g3_38+f8g2_19+f9g1_38;
  h[1] = f0g1+f1g0   +f2g9_19+f3g8_19+f4g7_19+f5g6_19+f6g5_19+f7g4_19+f8g3_19+f9g2_19;
  h[2] = f0g2+f1g1_2 +f2g0   +f3g9_38+f4g8_19+f5g7_38+f6g6_19+f7g5_38+f8g4_19+f9g3_38;
  h[3] = f0g3+f1g2   +f2g1   +f3g0   +f4g9_19+f5g8_19+f6g7_19+f7g6_19+f8g5_19+f9g4_19;
  h[4] = f0g4+f1g3_2 +f2g2   +f3g1_2 +f4g0   +f5g9_38+f6g8_19+f7g7_38+f8g6_19+f9g5_38;
  h[5] = f0g5+f1g4   +f2g3   +f3g2   +f4g1   +f5g0   +f6g9_19+f7g8_19+f8g7_19+f9g6_19;
  h[6] = f0g6+f1g5_2 +f2g4   +f3g3_2 +f4g2   +f5g1_2 +f6g0   +f7g9_38+f8g8_19+f9g7_38;
  h[7] = f0g7+f1g6   +f2g5   +f3g4   +f4g3   +f5g2   +f6g1   +f7g0   +f8g9_19+f9g8_19;
  h[8] = f0g8+f1g7_2 +f2g6   +f3g5_2 +f4g4   +f5g3_2 +f6g2   +f7g1_2 +f8g0   +f9g9_38;
  h[9] = f0g9+f1g8   +f2g7   +f3g6   +f4g5   +f5g4   +f6g3   +f7g2   +f8g1   +f9g0   ;

  return h;
}

public static void fe_mul(int[] h,int[] f,int[] g)
{

  long hr[] = fe_mul1(f, g);

  long carry0;
  long carry1;
  long carry2;
  long carry3;
  long carry4;
  long carry5;
  long carry6;
  long carry7;
  long carry8;
  long carry9;

  /*
  |h0| <= (1.65*1.65*2^52*(1+19+19+19+19)+1.65*1.65*2^50*(38+38+38+38+38))
    i.e. |h0| <= 1.4*2^60; narrower ranges for h2, h4, h6, h8
  |h1| <= (1.65*1.65*2^51*(1+1+19+19+19+19+19+19+19+19))
    i.e. |h1| <= 1.7*2^59; narrower ranges for h3, h5, h7, h9
  */

  carry0 = (hr[0] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[1] += carry0; hr[0] -= carry0 << 26;
  carry4 = (hr[4] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[5] += carry4; hr[4] -= carry4 << 26;
  /* |h0| <= 2^25 */
  /* |h4| <= 2^25 */
  /* |h1| <= 1.71*2^59 */
  /* |h5| <= 1.71*2^59 */

  carry1 = (hr[1] + (long) (1<<24)) >> 25; hr[2] += carry1; hr[1] -= carry1 << 25;
  carry5 = (hr[5] + (long) (1<<24)) >> 25; hr[6] += carry5; hr[5] -= carry5 << 25;
  /* |h1| <= 2^24; from now on fits into int32 */
  /* |h5| <= 2^24; from now on fits into int32 */
  /* |h2| <= 1.41*2^60 */
  /* |h6| <= 1.41*2^60 */

  carry2 = (hr[2] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[3] += carry2; hr[2] -= carry2 << 26;
  carry6 = (hr[6] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[7] += carry6; hr[6] -= carry6 << 26;
  /* |h2| <= 2^25; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h6| <= 2^25; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h3| <= 1.71*2^59 */
  /* |h7| <= 1.71*2^59 */

  carry3 = (hr[3] + (long) (1<<24)) >> 25; hr[4] += carry3; hr[3] -= carry3 << 25;
  carry7 = (hr[7] + (long) (1<<24)) >> 25; hr[8] += carry7; hr[7] -= carry7 << 25;
  /* |h3| <= 2^24; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h7| <= 2^24; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h4| <= 1.72*2^34 */
  /* |h8| <= 1.41*2^60 */

  carry4 = (hr[4] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[5] += carry4; hr[4] -= carry4 << 26;
  carry8 = (hr[8] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[9] += carry8; hr[8] -= carry8 << 26;
  /* |h4| <= 2^25; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h8| <= 2^25; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h5| <= 1.01*2^24 */
  /* |h9| <= 1.71*2^59 */

  carry9 = (hr[9] + (long) (1<<24)) >> 25; hr[0] += carry9 * 19; hr[9] -= carry9 << 25;
  /* |h9| <= 2^24; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h0| <= 1.1*2^39 */

  carry0 = (hr[0] + (long) (1<<25)) >> 26; hr[1] += carry0; hr[0] -= carry0 << 26;
  /* |h0| <= 2^25; from now on fits into int32 unchanged */
  /* |h1| <= 1.01*2^24 */

  h[0] = (int)hr[0];
  h[1] = (int)hr[1];
  h[2] = (int)hr[2];
  h[3] = (int)hr[3];
  h[4] = (int)hr[4];
  h[5] = (int)hr[5];
  h[6] = (int)hr[6];
  h[7] = (int)hr[7];
  h[8] = (int)hr[8];
  h[9] = (int)hr[9];
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Alex i think this is the solution to your issue. Catching exceptions from a synchronized block fails at *run time* with the following exception:Rejecting class fr.inra.arttest.MyClass because it failed compile-time verification. So check around any calls to synchronized. Also you can read more about the issue from this google bug post. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80961.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've double checked everything, there is no synchronized block anywhere on it's way. So problem probably relies somewhere else.